# xmllint: Get an item from a list using

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xmllint

I read a number of xmllint answers about similar issue, but none seemed applicable to my specific case (maybe I missed it). Anyway, I have a following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
  <item>
    <name>Name 1</name>
    <value>3</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Name 2</name>
    <value>4</value>
    <othervalue>5</othervalue>
  </item>
</items>
```

I want to select "value" from "item" of a specific name, but when I enter

```
xmllint --xpath '//items/item[@name="Name 1"]' test.xml
```

I get:

```
XPath set is empty
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
```

I suspect because "name" is not a property inside the "item" tag, but I'm not sure how deal with that, is there a way to iterate through items and check each one for name (using a bash script perhaps)?

Comment: @Daniel Haley That works, thanks. Can you add it as answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` isn't an attribute so it shouldn't be prefixed with `@` (which is [abbreviated syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) for `attribute::`).

Try:

```
/items/item[name="Name 1"]/value
```